# Callstack exceeded without even any recursion.. what's going on?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, callstack

Anyone've any idea why this might be incurring a call stack? I'm not even recursing.

The error:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\j\Desktop\bmrepl\STEAL\dedup.js:7
  this.push.apply(this, rest);
            ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Array.pluck (C:\Documents and Settings\j\Desktop\bmrepl\STEAL\dedup.js:7:13)
    at eatDupe (C:\Documents and Settings\j\Desktop\bmrepl\STEAL\dedup.js:46:15)

    at common (C:\Documents and Settings\j\Desktop\bmrepl\STEAL\dedup.js:39:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Documents and Settings\j\Desktop\bmrepl\STEAL\dedup.js:51:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

And, `dedup.js`:

```
var input = require('prompt'), sugar = require('sugar');

Array.prototype.pluck = function(i) {
  var el = this[i];
  var rest = this.slice(i + 1 || this.length);
  this.length = i < 0 ? this.length + i : i;
  this.push.apply(this, rest);
  return el;
};




var s = require('fs').readFileSync('NLD_EXSORT.json', {encoding: 'utf8'});
var arr = JSON.parse(s);

if ( arr.filter(function(el){ return el.filter(function(el){ return typeof el != 'string'; }).length != 0; }).length !== 0 ) throw 'nested arrays?'


console.log('all good');

// input.start();







var unq = [];

(function(){

    var dupeDate;

        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        unq.push(arr[i]);
        while(dupeDate = eatDupe())
            arr[i].push(dupeDate)
        }

    function eatDupe(){
        if (!arr[i+1]) return false;
        if (cmp(arr[i], arr[i+1]) > 2)
            return arr.pluck(i+1).pop();
        else
            return false;
    }

})();

console.log(unq.length);




function cmp(a, b){
  var common = 0;

  while(common < a.length || common < b.length){
    if(a[common] == b[common])
      common++;
    else
      return common;
  }
  if ( a.length == b.length ) return a.length;
  else throw 'CMP_ERR';
}
```

SO is complaining that it's too much code, but it I could trim it down more, I would've done so already. So Lorem ipsum dolor maybe this isn't necessary, idk.

Comment: Unfortunately now the line numbers in the error message seem not to match with the reduced code anymore, right?!

Comment: sorry, fixed @ghost23

Comment: Debug your code, check what's in `arr` at each iteration of `eatDupe`.

Comment: In line 5 you say either i + 1 or this.length, but this.length would always be too big to be used as an index. Could it be, that rest is an invalid array and thus passing it via apply results in the error?

Comment: no, rest would in that case be an empty array, @ghost23

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `[].push()` is somehow recursive internally when called with more than one argument. It's easily confirmable:

```
var arr = [];

arr.push.apply(arr, new Array(130000));
// RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

To avoid this error I'd suggest you push it iteratively instead of `this.push.apply`:

```
Array.prototype.pluck = function(i) {
  var el = this[i];
  var rest = this.slice(i + 1 || this.length);
  var k, l;

  this.length = i < 0 ? this.length + i : i;
  this.push.apply(this, rest);

  for(k = 0 l = rest.length; k < l; k++) {
    this.push(rest[k]);
  }

  return el;
};
```

Also I think `this.splice(i, 1)` would be equivalent to that whole function (though I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do).